# values does not show in my Modal

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, bootstrap-modal

The values of the textboxs does not come up. whats wrong with my code? the modal shows up but it does not get the values of the table. I made a rowcommand of it and put the code in there. but no show. can someone help me please.

Thank you!

This is my .cs code

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);



        GridViewRow gvrow = GridView1.Rows[i];
        txtID.Text = gvrow.Cells[0].Text;
        txtType.Text = gvrow.Cells[1].Text;
        txtModel.Text = gvrow.Cells[2].Text;
        txtQuan.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[3].Text);
        txtUnit.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[4].Text);
        txtDate.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[5].Text);
        txtDesc.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[6].Text);


        //txtID.Text = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text.ToString();


            lblResult.Visible = false;

            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(@"<script type='text/javascript'>");
            sb.Append("$('#editModal').modal('show');");
            sb.Append(@"</script>");
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "EditModalScript", sb.ToString(), false);


    }
```

Here is my modal div code

```
<div id="editModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
                <h3 id="editModalLabel">View Details</h3>
            </div>    
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upEdit" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class ="modal-body">
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <td>Item ID:
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Type:
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtType" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Model:
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtModel" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Requested Quantity:
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuan" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Unit:
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUnit" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Date Needed:
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Description:
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesc" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <asp:Label ID="lblResult" Visible="false" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Button ID ="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Approve" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
            <button class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView1" EventName="RowCommand" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID ="btnSave" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

MARKUP OF My GRIDVIEW 1

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="panel1" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="TransactionID" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_OnRowDataBound" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" CellPadding="4" AllowPaging="true" PageIndex="2" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" HeaderStyle-BackColor ="CornflowerBlue" BorderWidth="1" BorderColor="Gray" Width="100%" CssClass=" table table-hover" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server"  />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <img style="cursor:pointer" src ="../Images/Icons/plus2.png" />
                <asp:Panel ID ="pnlDetails" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvDet" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="ChildGrid">
                        <Columns>
                            <%--<asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="20px" DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />--%>
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="200px" DataField="ItemType" HeaderText="Type" />
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="250px" DataField="ItemModel" HeaderText="Model" />
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="140px" DataField="ItemQuantity" HeaderText="Requested Quantity" />
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="80px" DataField="ItemUnit" HeaderText="Unit" />
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="100px" DataField="ItemDate" HeaderText="Date Needed" />
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="200px" DataField="ItemDesc" HeaderText="Description" />
                            <%--<asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="80px" DataField="ItemStatus" HeaderText="Status" />--%>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </asp:Panel>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Transaction Number" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID ="lblmosID" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind ("TransactionID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Width="30px" Font-Size="15px" Font-Names="Calibri" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID ="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind ("DateFiled") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Width="130px" Font-Names="Calibri" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID ="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind ("ReqName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Font-Names="Calibri" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Company" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID ="lblComp" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind ("ReqCompany") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Font-Names="Calibri" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Branch" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID ="lblBranch" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind ("ReqBranch") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Font-Names ="Calibri" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Business Unit" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID ="lblBU" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind ("ReqBU") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Font-Names="Calibri" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Department" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID ="lblDept" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind ("ReqDept") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Font-Names="Calibri" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Section" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID ="lblsection" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind ("ReqSection") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Font-Names="Calibri" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID ="lblStatus" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind ("TransStatus") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Font-Names="Calibri" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <%--<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID ="lnkEdit" runat="server" Text="View" PostBackUrl='<%# "Details.aspx?Id=" + Eval("TransactionID") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>--%>
        <asp:ButtonField CommandName="editRecord" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-info" ButtonType="Button" Text="View" HeaderText="View Request" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
        <ControlStyle CssClass ="btn btn-info" />    
        </asp:ButtonField>
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="CornflowerBlue" />
</asp:GridView>
         </ContentTemplate>
     <Triggers>
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView1" />
     </Triggers>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Whats wrong with my code?

Thanks!

Comment: try to use AutoPostBack="true" for textbox

Comment: Please post the markup of your GridView control

Comment: posted below Denis

Comment: hi Denis, updated my question. thanks

Comment: Thank you Jedi.Have a look at the answer I posted.Let's see if it helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried re-creating your problem on my side but it seems to be working.The only major differences I have in my code is I used `AutoGenerateSelectButton="True"` on the `GridView` and `EnableCdn="true"` on the `ScriptManager` control.Have a look at the code below and see if you can spot something odd that your logic is not doing and figure out why yours is not working.I hope it helps you.

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class DisplayGridViewRowInPopup : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            GetData();
        }
    }

    public void GetData()
    {
        var p1 = new Product { TransactionID = 1, ItemType = "Type1", ItemModel = "Model1", ItemQuantity = 1, ItemUnit = "Unit1", ItemDate = DateTime.Now, ItemDesc = "Product 1" };
        var p2 = new Product { TransactionID = 2, ItemType = "Type2", ItemModel = "Model2", ItemQuantity = 2, ItemUnit = "Unit2", ItemDate = DateTime.Now, ItemDesc = "Product 2" };
        GridView1.DataSource = new List<Product> { p1, p2 };
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        GridViewRow gvrow = GridView1.Rows[i];
        txtID.Text = gvrow.Cells[1].Text;
        txtType.Text = gvrow.Cells[2].Text;
        txtModel.Text = gvrow.Cells[3].Text;
        txtQuan.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[4].Text);
        txtUnit.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[5].Text);
        txtDate.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[6].Text);
        txtDesc.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[7].Text);

        lblResult.Visible = false;
        string script = "<script type='text/javascript'>$('#editModal').modal('show');</script>";
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "EditModalScript", script, false);
    }
}

public class Product
{
    public int TransactionID { get; set; }
    public string ItemType { get; set; }
    public string ItemModel { get; set; }
    public int ItemQuantity { get; set; }
    public string ItemUnit { get; set; }
    public DateTime ItemDate { get; set; }
    public string ItemDesc { get; set; }
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableCdn="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <div id="editModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
                        <h3 id="editModalLabel">View Details</h3>
                    </div>
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upEdit" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <table class="table">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Item ID:
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Type:
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtType" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Model:
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtModel" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Requested Quantity:
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuan" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Unit:
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUnit" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Date Needed:
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Description:
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesc" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblResult" Visible="false" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Approve" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
                                <button class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView1" EventName="RowCommand" />
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSave" EventName="Click" />
                        </Triggers>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True">
                </asp:GridView>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
             <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView1" />
         </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image: Displaying GridView row edit template in modal popup]

Comment: hi Denis, it worked for you maybe because your data is preloaded? mine my data comes from the database and i bind it

Comment: That doesn't matter,Just make sure you bind your data once by using if(!Page.IsPostBack).It makes no difference if you are binding to a database or to a static list of data in this context

Comment: can i send you my project? if its okay with you

Comment: Ok and send me your database as well - denis.wessels7@gmail.com

Comment: Hi Denis, just sent it.